# KVO: Apparently the same "effective" keyPath produce different results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I have struggled with the setup of KVO for a few hours and I managed to get it to work:

This works:

```
 [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"session.loginState" options:0 context:nil];
```

This doesn't:

```
 [self addObserver:self.session forKeyPath:@"loginState" options:0 context:nil];
```

Please note that `self.session` lazily creates an empty `Session` object so self.session is never `nil`. However, it seems that:

1. the keypath `session.loginState` of `self` is not the same as...
2. the keypath `loginState` of `self.session` from a KVO perspective

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your observer and observee backwards. Try

```
[self.session addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loginState" options:0 context:nil];
```

Comment: Silly mistake, seems like I missed the forrest for the trees, or the selves in my case :-)

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
 [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"session.loginState" options:0 context:nil];
```

You are adding self as an observer of `self`'s keypath `session.loginState`, that is effectively `self.session.loginState`.

In this code:

```
 [self addObserver:self.session forKeyPath:@"loginState" options:0 context:nil];
```

You are adding `self.session` as an observer of `self`'s keypath `loginState`, that is effectively `self.loginState`.